# toString method call to void method

Tags: java, list, tostring

Hey guys i'm working on a program and i've run into a weird problem that hopefully is an easy fix. So I'm given the shell code for a program that creates and prints a link list of integers. and it has the print() method to format the printing output. Then I am asked to create a toString method that returns a String containing the print value of the list. Here is my code:

```
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.print("List elements: ");
    IntNode temp = front;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        System.out.print(temp.val + " ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    System.out.println("\n-----------------------\n");
}

public String toString()
{
    String result;
    result += System.out.print(print());
    return result;
}
```

As you might expect I get an error from the compiler saying 'void' type not allowed here.

Comment: @joey.enfield if you read the code, you will find it very explicit, I think.

Comment: .. I did.. there are so many problems here...

Comment: I would expect you to get an error, since you can't use string concatenation with void.  What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is basically that you want/need a `String` from the `print` method. Your current design is:

- `print`: prints this class instance using different `String`s I want/need.
- `toString`: try using the generated `String` in `print`.

As can be noted, this is a **design problem**. The implementation should be the other way around: `toString` method generating the desired `String` form of the object reference and `print` method just printing the result of `toString`.

So, just adapt your code in `toString` method to accomplish what you want/need:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("--------------------");
    sb.append('\n');
    sb.append("List elements: ");
    while (temp != null) {
        sb.append(temp.val);
        sb.append(" ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    sb.append("\n-----------------------\n");
    return sb.toString();
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something weird here:

`result += System.out.print(print());`

Your method `print()` does not return a value and just prints everything to console. You can need to modify `print` to return a String value.

Even better, you need to do make a proper `toString()` method which is based on the code from the current `print` method and just use `toString()` in your `print`.

Comment: Even if `print` returns a string, it'll still break, because `System.out.print()` also returns void. `+=` is undefined for type void.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your System output with your Strings. This isn't how I would write it personally, but it seems to be what you're after.

```
public String getAsString()
{
    String output = new String();
    output += "--------------------\n";
    output += "List elements: \n";
    IntNode temp = front;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        output += (temp.val + " \n");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    output += "\n-----------------------\n");

    return output;
}

public String toString()
{
    return getAsString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I think the wording on the lab just threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

```
result += System.out.print(print());
```

Is the problematic line. You cannot assign a console print to a variable.

Instead, use string variables throughout your program and print the final result to the console.

Comment: OP already knows about this: *As you might expect I get an error from the compiler saying `void` type not allowed here*.

Comment: Then I don't really understand what the issue is? If the OP already knows that is the reason for his problem then surely he can solve it?

Comment: It is a design problem, as I noted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this. Note I'm using stringbuilder which is better than many string con-cats.

I'm making a lot of assumption from your code... but you are probally trying to do something like this.

```
public String print(){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append("--------------------\n");
    result.append("List elements: ");
    IntNode temp = front;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        result.append(temp.val);
        result.append(" ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    result.append("\n-----------------------\n");
    return result.toString()
}

public String toString()
{
    return print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what, if anything, `System.out.print` returns, but I'm sure that appending its return value to a string is not how you want to do this.

I would make the `print()` method use `toString` to build the formatted string:

```
public String toString() {
    String output = "--------------------\n";
    output += "List elements: ";
    IntNode temp = front;
    while (temp != null) {
        output += temp.val + " ";
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    output += "\n-----------------------\n";
    return output;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.print(toString());
}
```

Note: You could also `StringBuilder` to build the string in `toString`, which would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.print(print())
```

This statement is calling the method you have defined in your code.The return type of method in your code is void , which says I will not return anything and print method under `PrintStream` class accepts parameter , which can in turn be parsed into String.

Return some value and then try to print